# Grails JMS Plugin - Not receiving messages

Tags: grails, jms, oracle-aq

I installed the Grails JMS pluign into my application, but am not receiving any messages. My config is as follows:

In resources.groovy

```
jmsConnectionFactory(package.OracleAqFactoryBean) {
    dataSource = ref("dataSource")
}
```

In config.groovy

```
jms {
    containers {
        standard {
            autoStartup = true
            connectionFactoryBean = "jmsConnectionFactory"
        }
    }
}
```

In my Grails Service:

```
class MyService {

    static exposes = ["jms"]
    static destination = "queuename"
    static listenerCount = 5


    void onMessage(msg) {
        // handle message
        println "WE GOT A MESSAGE...."
    }
}
```

In Datasource.groovy

```
    dataSource {
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@restofurl"
        username = "xxx"
        password = "xxxx"
    }
```

We have a connection to the queue working using standard Spring config in a standard Java app, but that spring config does not work if imported in the Grails app, which is why we are trying to use the jms plugin.

Comment: Your jms provider is an Oracle database?

Comment: That's correct. The queue is an Oracle AQ.